# How to know the file served in a web request

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver

My question is clear, in a web server request without a file name like

```
http://whatever.com/path_1/path_b/
```

when the web server response is obtained with the "welcome-file-list" (in the web.xml of Tomcat app) with the default possible pages (deafult.html, index.html, etc.).
Is there a way of knowing wich exactly file, or the file name, is server by the web server?

I need to check the file in a filter, but in the request and/or response objects doesn't seem to be available

Thanks

Comment: What's the business objective? E.g. it might help to know what you want to achieve (rather than how you want to achieve this). This way somebody might be able to provide a standard compliant solution to the underlying problem rather than letting you know how your proposed solution can be implemented

Comment: I think the objective is clear, I need to know the file (filename) that the web server (catalina in Tomcat) is serving when it is used a default page in the url of the browser, like "http://anyway/"; when in the server there are definded various default pages (welcome-file-list)

Comment: I consider this to be the technical objective: You don't state the underlying "business" problem - rather some arbitrary solution that you came up with that requires that you know this filename. As this solution you require is not obvious, knowing the problem (why do you need to know this) might help pointing you to an alternative, standard-conforming solution for the same problem. That's what I asked for, and you don't state this in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. the purpose of hiding the physical details of file and its access behind a web-server is to provide a streamlined and secured access to the resources of a server.

Comment: But I'm inside the server, there is no need to secure the access to any resource. It's not about the User Navigation point of view.

Comment: you want to know the mapping defined ?

Comment: Inside my own application, in a servlet filter, I need to know wich exactly welcome file of the list is served.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've tried this solution, but I don't know if it is too much "resource-consuming".

In my servlet filter, check the welcome file list of files  for the first existing one.

```
String fullURL = httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
String realPath = this.servletContext.getRealPath(filePath);

// if path is not a filename
if (fullURL.endsWith("/")){
    // welcome file list
    for (String wf : (String[])servletContext.getAttribute("org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES")) {
        // first encountered - first used
        if ((new File(realPath+"\\"+wf)).exists()) {
            // el primero que exista será el utilizado
            fullURL += wf;
            realPath += "\\"+wf;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```